# Page loads, then auto-reloads and give a 404 error

Tags: asp.net-mvc, internet-explorer, firefox, web

I have a (quite old) web asp.net-mvc application which is optimized for IE8.

It has the following in the `head` of its main masterpage:

```
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=EmulateIE8" />
```

On any regular day, everything works "just fine".

Some days, however, some of the main views seem to refresh one time too many and give a 404 error.

Here are some infos:

- I use IE11 in IE8 compatibility mode
- The latest (observed) occurences of the problem were on

| Year\Month | 01 | 04 | 09 | 11 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2017 |  |  | Tue 26 | Wed 29 |
| 2018 |  | Wed 25 | Tue 25 | Wed 28 |
| 2020 | Mon 27 |  |  | Wed 25 |
| 2021 | Mon 25 | Wed 28 |  |  |

- Everytime, the views affected by the problem on IE are correctly displayed on Firefox
- The problem usually just "disappears" the day after
- If I stop the loading just on time, everything is displayed as it should

  - data are shown in grid
  - filters are working
  - buttons are working
  - pop-up forms are working
- If I stop the loading just on time, and then hit refresh (F5), the 404 error doesn't show up
- If I click in the address bar and hit enter when already on the 404 view, I can see the page load, but the 404 comes back
- If when on 404 view I hit F12, then click in the address bar and hit enter, the page loads as it should, and no 404 error, I even can navigate to any of the affected views without encountering a 404 error as long as I don't close the developper tools window
- The problem doesn't show in development, only in production

I'm wondering what could possibly be the origin of this strange behaviour. Is it possible that IE acts differently some specific days? And why would F12 change IE's behaviour?

At first I was thinking that maybe a function implying dates could be on an edge case, but I really can't figure out which edge case would imply 09/26/2017, 11/29/2017, 04/25/2018, 09/25/2018 and 11/28/2018.
From the possible pattern observed, I expect next bug to happen on 09/28/2021 (last Tuesday of September).

---

Here is what my emulation tab looks like today on the page that redirected to a 404 yesterday (also the bug disappeared this time too without having done anything):

[image: F12 Emulation tab]

IE security zone is "*Trusted sites | Protected mode : disabled*"

I don't know about the Group Policy

---

### Edit 11/28/2018:

The bug occurs again today. I'd be very happy to do whatever could help finding out the cause of it.
I start to think that there might be something cyclic in this bug (09/26/2017 - 09/25/2018 and 11/29/2017 - 11/28/2018 seem to be 364 days cycle)

Knowing it happened on 04/25/2018, I'm therefore expecting to see next occurence on 04/24/2019

### Edit 01/25/2021:

Again occurring. Using F12, I noticed that the affected pages show as POST requests with IE8, when it should be (and is with IE9+) GET:

| Emulation mode | Method | Result |
| --- | --- | --- |
| IE8 | POST | 401 Unauthorized |
| IE8 | POST | 404 Not Found |
| IE9+ | GET | 200 OK |

### Edit 06/28/2021:

This is usual navigation workflow:

| Request | Method | Result |
| --- | --- | --- |
| BasePage | GET | 200 OK |
| GridData | POST | 200 OK |
| GridData | POST | 200 OK |

This is navigation workflow happening on bug days:

| Request | Method | Result |
| --- | --- | --- |
| BasePage | GET | 200 OK |
| GridData | POST | 200 OK |
| **BasePage** | POST | **404 Not Found** |

Obviously the last request leads to a 404 as my `BasePage` is declared like:

```
[HttpGet]
public ActionResult BasePage()
{
    // irrelevent
}
```

Comment: Hi, what does f12>Emulation tab say? Which IE security zone is the site mapped to on your computer? (File>Properties menu).... expected intranet. Does your company use Group Policy and Enterprise Site Mode lists? From your description it sounds like either you have 2 x-ua meta elements or there is a x-ua header (see the response header in the Networking tab of the f12 dev tool.

Comment: @RobParsons I've added informations. Sadly I can't test anything more as the problem disappeared, but even if I had 2 x-ua meta elements, why would it bug only on several days, and stop the next day without any modification? Also, I'm unsure if F12 can help me as it seems to modify IE's behaviour (bug without, no bug with)

Comment: If its gone away, no problem..... However, why do you continue to use the IE8 x-ua? You would only do that for legacy intranet apps (running in the IE Intranet (LAN) security zone), and you would use Enterprise Site MOde lists to do that...

Comment: It is gone for now. As mentioned in my question, it is a recurring issue, it only lasts one day each time, and I have no idea why... This is indeed a legacy intranet app, which is planned to be entirely switched next year, and I have no access to "enterprise site mode lists"

Comment: are you maintainig any session/token anything like that ?

Comment: @ArunprasanthKV yes, I'd like to read the idea behing this question, as how it would break on some specific days (meaning everything goes fine the next day) and how F12 could change this behaviour

Comment: I just tested with & without "Persist Emulation" and behaviour didn't change (bug without F12, no bug with F12)

Comment: yes chances are there you can off this in the Persist Emulation settings in IE, Or else check is there any logic defined in your system related to window resize

Comment: are you using console object and its methods? IE may act like this when you have consoles in your production code.

Comment: You mean `window.console` in javascript?

Comment: yes window.console or condole.log()  and any of the condole methods.

Comment: There are many calls to `window.console` and `console.log()` but they are in plug-ins (aspNetAjaxLibrary, aspNetMvc and firebug-lite) is there any way to detect from the browser which call is causing this bug?